# Scala hello-world template gives: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have trouble pulling the hello-world template from GitHub as part of the following tutorial:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/sbt-track/getting-started-with-scala-and-sbt-on-the-command-line.html

With the command in terminal (run as Administrator):

```
sbt new scala/hello-world.g8
```

The error that I receive is:
[launcher] error during sbt launcher: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/Trees

system settings:

- Windows 10
- Java JDK version 1.8.0_221
- SBT 1.5.0
- Spark 2.4.7
- Python 3.9.2

Hints how to solve this are highly appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on my own question:
Since sbt couldn't find a build.sbt file in the respective directory. Press c and enter.
Go to this directory in your terminal and give the command sbt:
[image: terminal will show:]

Your build.sbt folder will be created and the following command will work:)

```
 sbt new scala/hello-world.g8
```